# ¿Como hago para que una variable me tome el valor de una caja de texto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de hacer una comparación en javascript pero cuando de trato de traer el valor de la caja hacia la variable me dice que esta es indefinida dejo el código aquí abajo. uso la caja de texto para que el usuario coloque el valor numérico y uso la función click del botón para iniciar la función resaltar.

```js
//el codigo que resalta los tiempos de la fullMatriz
var tiempoCarrera = document.getElementById("tiempoC");
var comparacion = document.getElementById("comparation");
comparacion.addEventListener("click", resaltar);
//funcion para resaltar valores menores de lo indicado

function resaltar() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      if (tiempoCarrera>fullMatriz[i][j]) {
        document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "-good-");
      }
      else {
        document.write(fullMatriz[i][j] + "------");
      }
    }
    document.write("</br>");
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="ejecutarautomatica1.js"></script>
    <p>Este es el subprogrma para marcar los tiempos menores al ingresado aquí abajo
      <br/>ingrese el tiempo aqui abajo
      <br/><input type="number" id="tiempoC"/>
      <input type="button" value="iniciar comparación" width="300" height="50" id="comparation"/>

    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me aparece un error en  `fullMatriz` me dice que no esta definida te hace falta ese pedazo de codigo ?

Answer (score 0):

**OnKeydown**
En tu input:  `<input type="number" id="tiempoC"/>` Agrega un funcion que se ejecute al escribir. Ejemplo una llamada `Search`  de esta manera:
 `<input type="number" id="tiempoC" onkeydown="Search(this)"/>`.

**Setear una variable con su valor:**

```
function Search(x) {
    if(x.value) {
       console.log('El Valor del input es' + x.value);
    }
}
```

Listo ya esta ahora `x.value` tiene el valor de tu input y puedes hacer las respectivas validaciones y guardarlo. Lo que tu quieras :)

> El if (x.value) es para verificar que `x.value` no este vacio

Comment: en donde colocas this que deberia ir

Comment: Me sigue saliendo que la variable tiempoCarrera esta indefinida

Answer (score 0):

El valor es indefinido porque solo estas manipulando el `input` pero no su valor, para obtener el valor de un `input` debes utilizar `.value` en Javascript.

```js
var tiempoCarrera = document.getElementById('tiempoC');
var comparacion = document.getElementById('comparation');
comparacion.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = tiempoCarrera.value;
});
```

```html
<p>Este es el subprogrma para marcar los tiempos menores al ingresado aquí abajo
  <br />ingrese el tiempo aqui abajo
  <br /><input type="number" id="tiempoC" />
  <input type="button" value="iniciar comparación" width="300" height="50" id="comparation" />
</p>
<p id="resultado">
</p>
```